# TableView Cell Color resets after scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am using swift to make one of my first apps, I want to be able to change the colors of specific cells depending on weather or not the have been selected and added to selectedHobbies. Whenever doing this it seems to work but when I scroll down and back up the cells seem to reset to the original color.

```
import UIKit

var selectedHobbies : [String] = [] //Hold a global value of the 
selected hobbies
 var numberSelected:Int = 0 //Hold the number of selected hobbies


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, 
UISearchResultsUpdating {





var filteredHobbies = [String]() //The hobbies filted by the search bar
var searchController = UISearchController()
var resultController = UITableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultController)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.resultController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.resultController.tableView.dataSource = self



    }
    //updates search results according to what is in the search bar, filters hobbies out that dont contain the same string of text
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredHobbies = hobbies.filter({ (hobbies: String) -> Bool in

            if hobbies.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
            {
                return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }

        })

        self.resultController.tableView.reloadData()
    }




   // number of
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }
//swipe actions for table view
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let important = importantAction(at: indexPath)
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [important])
    }
//takes the hobby according to the searched hobbies (if they are filtered)
func importantAction(at IndexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    var hobby = ""
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        hobby = hobbies[IndexPath.row]

    } else {
        hobby = filteredHobbies[IndexPath.row]
    }

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Important") { (action, view, completion) in
        completion(true)
    }
    // wont add hobbies otherwise
    if selectedHobbies.contains(hobby){
        action.title = "Add Hobby"
        action.backgroundColor = .gray

        print(selectedHobbies)
        return action

    }else {
    // adds hobbies if they arent in the array
        selectedHobbies.append(hobby)
        action.title = "Add Hobby"
        tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        action.backgroundColor = .green
        numberSelected += 1
        if numberSelected >= 10 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: nil)
            print(selectedHobbies)
        }
        print(selectedHobbies)
        return action
    }
}
func removeAction(at IndexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    var hobby = ""
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        hobby = hobbies[IndexPath.row]
    } else {
        hobby = filteredHobbies[IndexPath.row]
    }

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Important") { (action, view, completion) in
        completion(true)
    }
    if selectedHobbies.contains(hobby){ //removes hobby if in selected hobbies

        selectedHobbies = selectedHobbies.filter{$0 != hobby}
        action.title = "Remove Hobby"
        action.backgroundColor = .red
        numberSelected -= 1

        print(selectedHobbies)
        return action
    }else {
        action.title = "Remove Hobby"
        action.backgroundColor = .gray
        print(selectedHobbies)
        return action
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let remove = removeAction(at: indexPath)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [remove])
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if tableView == resultController.tableView
        {
            return self.filteredHobbies.count
        }
        else
        {
            return self.hobbies.count
        }

    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()


        if tableView == resultController.tableView
        {

            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredHobbies [indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.hobbies[indexPath.row]
        }



        return cell




    }


 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: You need to set the color in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAt` selectedHobbies  check if object is in  selectedHobbies and color Cell according to that

```
   if selectedHobbies.contains(hobby){

     }else{

   }
```

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean, where do I insert the given lines of code?

Comment: At `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Where can I modify cellForRowAt. Sorry I'm very new to programming in general.

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

Comment: Like this?         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   
            
            if selectedHobbies.contains(hobby){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            }else{
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
            
            return cell
            
            
            
            
        }